# Memory leak and errors after fixing memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Can you tell me why I have bunch of errors after editing memory leaks?? I wanted to fix memory leaks which i did. All memory is free....But suddenly i got bunch of errors.. Why its happened??? Any explanations?!

Comment: Please don't program by guessing keywords or functions. Learn systematically, get a book, read manuals, follow examples, etc.

Comment: What errors?  Have you run a profiler against your code?

Comment: `List *node = malloc(sizeof(List)); free(node);` — what are you expecting this code to do?

Comment: You malloc memory and then free it, then you USE IT ANYWAYS. This code is so broken it's not even funny.

Comment: Ah, But all the memory is indeed `free`d. No memory leaks here.

Comment: Well there are memory leaks though!!! How to fix them???Only with free()!! Also I dont use pointer anymore after malloc!! node->list etc it is a struct node which have the same name as a pointer!!!

Comment: Yes! But I have bunch of errors which I cant fix...@Quirliom

Comment: How can you say you don't use the pointer (either node or str) after malloc, when it appears on literally the next line after your free!?!

Comment: that node is the struct which is called NODE in my .h file! (the same name as a pinter)

Comment: struct node {
    int value;
    struct node * next;
};

Answer (score 1):

`free()` does not do what you appear to think it does. You use `free` on memory that you `malloc`ed *after* you have used it, when you're done with it.

With `free` you return the memory to the OS. It means you are no longer going to use it. Calling `free` immediately after `malloc` is like turning on your PC and then immediately shutting it down again.

The lines

```
List *node = malloc(sizeof(List));
free(node);
node->value = v; // can't use node after free()ing it
```

are problematic here because you allocate the memory. Then de-allocate (`free`) it and *then* use it anyway. Remove the call to `free` and call `free` in `remove_node` instead.